# BufferedReader maxing out at 76 Bytes

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

Win7, JSE...  I've invoked a BufferedReader to handle reading data from a file.

Reading the Java documentation, it says default size is "large enough for most purposes..."  reading Android's documentation, default size is over 8k characters...

My Buffered Reader is stuck at reading a max of 76 Bytes.  I can use default constructor, 100, 10000 as size inputs and still, 76Bytes max.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileObj);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
```

What am I missing here?  Would greatly simplify my code if I could trust that each readLine() command gave me a full line.

*EDIT* I'm using a BufferedReader because newLine is very important separator for an action I need to perform on the data in the file.  Only work around I have right now is to insert extra newLines into my written file and use 0-length readLine() as my separator.

*EDIT2* It seems that the culprit is how I'm writing the file from my other application.  I'm writing each "line" to a file in Android, but when I open the file in Windows and turn word wrap off, the content is still wrapped..... to 76 characters.  Time to investigate more.

Comment: What does your input file look like?  According to the documentation readLine will read until 'any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed' is encountered.  So if you are doing br.readLine() you should be guaranteed to get a full line.

Comment: Show us the actual code you use to read from `br`.

Comment: What do you mean by "76 byte max"?  Why do you believe its not 8 K when you set it to 8 K?

Comment: There seem to be many layers to this onion and I no longer believe my problem is with BufferedReader.  Will update original.